# Efetuar deslocamento de linha(lead function) fazendo com que a última linha seja 0 ao invés de 'NULL'

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou utilizando subconsultas correlacionadas para simular a função LEAD pois meu MySQL não suporta esta função, realizando o deslocamento das linhas de uma coluna. Porém ao deslocar, seja através da função LEAD original ou do código abaixo que implementei, a ultima linha apresenta valor NULL, me impossibilitando de realizar a operação de subtração.

O código é (pego em:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187933/simulate-effective-lead1-or-lead2-in-mysql):

```
SELECT t1.digit, t2.digit,t1.digit -t2.digit as 'diff'
FROM (
    SELECT digit, @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS id
    FROM
     alfabet  , (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
    ORDER BY
     alfabet.digit ASC
) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT digit, @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS id
    FROM
     alfabet  , (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
    ORDER BY
     alfabet.digit ASC
) AS t2
  ON t1.id +1 = t2.id;
```

Este funciona perfeitamente para mim, porém tenho como resultado:

```
digit   next_digit     diff
4       2              2         
2       2              0           
2       2              0          
2       1              1                  
1       NULL           NULL
```

Preciso fazer com que na coluna next_digit ao invés de NULL apareça o valor de 0, para que seja possível fazer a subtração e retornar em diff (1-0 = 1). Ou, alguma maneira de realizar a subtração com o NULL e ainda assim retornar o valor 1 na coluna diff, alguma operação que permita fazer (1-null = 1).

[RESOLVIDO]

Utilizando a função coalesce

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.cnt, t2.cnt_lead, coalesce (t1.cnt - t2.cnt_lead, t1.cnt) as 'diff'
``
```

Comment: Função COALESCE()?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Grato.  Caso alguém precise, ficou assim          
SELECT t1.name, t1.cnt, t2.cnt_lead, coalesce (t1.cnt - t2.cnt_lead, t1.cnt) as 'diff' dessa forma, se a subtração retornar null, ele mantém o valor da coluna original.